# Transition property on input width not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a simple todo list app. I want to increase the `width` of the text field when it is `hovered` on, over the course of `3 seconds`.

I have used `transition` property but it is not working correctly. **Problem** is that the `width` increases instantly when the mouse pointer is hovered on the text field instead of increasing over the course of `3 seconds`.

What am i doing wrong here?

Here's the code [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYxJEE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `input does not have width property in default state its auto`.

Transition will not work `auto to some value`.

just add `width` property to `input`. it will work.

**Here is the working code.**

```css
.main-container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: width 3s;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

input:hover {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="enter new item" />
  <button id="btn-add-item">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn-remove-item">Remove Last Item</button>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<!--end of main container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the changing CSS Property in the input that will change on hover like this.

```
input{
     width: 100px;
     transition: width 3s ease-out;
}
input:hover{
    width: 300px;
}
```

Your code miss width in input tag CSS.